# Cómo abrir un video en un modal o un fancybox desde un botón

Tags: jquery, html5

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Info</button>
```

lo quiero es que al darle clic a este botón se cargue un video en un modal o como fencybox

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado al momento?

Comment: he creado un modal y en modal pongo un iframe pero el video no se reproduce

Comment: agrega lo que lleves por favor

Comment: Ya lo resolvi, estaba colocando el el video en el body del modal lo cambie al header y me funciono muchas gracias por la disposición

Comment: Considera publicar tu solución o eliminar la pregunta para que esta publicación no quede a la deriva

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="modal fade" id="miModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/W6LxpZeIxNQ" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            Texto del modal
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#miModal">
Abrir modal
```

lo resolví al poner el video en el header del modal y no el body como lo estaba haciendo en un principio